# Cannot find gem in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm sure this is an easy question but I'm having a hard time figuring out what to Google.

I'm trying to use the library [ChunkyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png).

I added it to my `Gemfile` and did a `bundle install`.

```
bundle list | grep "chunky"
  * chunky_png (1.2.5)
```

So far so good.

I try using it in my controller:

```
image = ChunkyPNG::Canvas.from_data_url(params[:data]).to_image
```

(The docs for this method are available [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/wvanbergen/chunky_png/master/ChunkyPNG/Canvas/DataUrlImporting#from_data_url-instance_method))

It results in the following error:

```
NameError in MyController#create
    uninitialized constant MyController::ChunkyPNG
```

Why is prepending the controller namespace? I imagine that's what is causing the error.

Otherwise, it means that ChunkyPNG is not install (and it clearly is).

Am I not able to use this gem upfront without writing some sort of rails plugin to wrap around it?

Thanks

EDIT:

### Question has been answered, see @apneadiving's comment

Comment: what if you do `image = ::ChunkyPNG::Canvas::DataUrlImporting.from_data_url(params[:data]).to_image`

Comment: @apneadiving I had to restart my rails app but your comment works! Thanks so much :)

Comment: For reference, is your controller in a namespace ? e.g. `class NameSpace::MyController` ?

Comment: No, what I meant by that was that it was should `MyController::ChunkPNG` as if it were defined within my `MyController`.

Comment: @IanBishop I understand, this kind of uninitialized constant error usually occurs in a namespaced class. It could just be poorly written module code from ChunkyPng

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, or somewhere else in the app do:

`require 'chunky_png'`

Comment: Would work but how come it's not needed in console. Would just hide the real problem

Comment: The question is marked rails 3, requiring in the controller would go against rails 3's new approach to gem management.

Comment: @IanBishop Agreed, but the gems have to be written in a way that makes use of that. Also, sometimes you don't want your gems to be loaded all the time.